# Extract the data from NC file using R studio

Tags: r, dplyr, r-raster, cdo-climate, ncdf4

I have the NC file with 0.5 resolution containing yearly PDSI index from 1900 to 2013 of globe. how can I get the one value for each year for entire Europe/Asia/America.
thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried the `library(ncdf4)`?

Comment: Write nico clearer. For me, an NC file means a program for numerical machines. Give as an example.
Generally speaking, if the file is in text format then:
1. Load it using the `readr` package
2. Process it using `dplyr`
3. Visualize using `ggplot2`

You can find all these packages in the `tidyverse`.

Comment: If you show the code you are using, starting with `library` calls to load the required packages, we might be able to help you move forward from wherever you are getting stuck.

Comment: sorry NC means ncdf file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `extract` or `zonal` methods in the `terra` package (or the older `raster` package). For a more detailed answer you should ask a better question, that shows what you have tried, and where exactly you get stuck. If you do not know where to start, perhaps begin with [this tutorial](https://rspatial.org/terra/index.html); and you can also consult the existing questions on this site (search for raster, extract, ncdf).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by the language requirements as you have R-studio in the title but tagged the question with cdo.

If you are happy to use cdo, you can cut out a region of choice with

```
cdo sellonlatbox,lon1,lon2,lat1,lat2 in.nc out.nc
```

You can then spatially average this file with

```
cdo fldmean in.nc out.nc
```

you can combine these two using piping

```
cdo fldmean -sellonlatmean,lon1,lon2,lat1,lat2 in.nc out.nc
```